# How to use '?' in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Suppose I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE ( username = 'foo' OR email = 'bar' )
```

How would I make it so, that query uses ? marks instead of passing values in directly. eg.

```
SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE ( username = ? OR email = ? ...
```

And have input specified within WHERE () clauses if possible.

EDIT: I've read somewhere a while ago that using ? marks in queries improves performance and helps with sql injections. This is what I am trying to do here.

Comment: What flavour of SQL? Typically this would be a function of the client/code that is sending the query to the database server

Comment: `?` is used to define place holders. And are used with prepared statements. What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to do SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE ( 'username = ? OR email = ?', 'foo', 'bar') so foo and bar replace placeholders.

Comment: Are you executing your SQL from the `mysql`/`psql` interface? From within a procedure? Or perhaps through some language's database interface? And are you using MySQL or PostgreSQL? I'm guessing the former since PostgreSQL would complain about `'users'`.

Comment: Executing from mysql shell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `MySQL`, the question mark symbol that you can find in your query is called the parameter placeholder. It is usually used when you are creating a `Prepare` statement (*dynamic sql*). ex,

```
SET @s = 'SELECT SQRT(POW(?,2) + POW(?,2)) AS hypotenuse';
PREPARE stmt2 FROM @s;
SET @a = 6;
SET @b = 8;
EXECUTE stmt2 USING @a, @b;
```

- [SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)
- [PostgreSQL PREPARE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html)

**UPDATE 1**

here's an example of select based on your data above,

```
SET @s = 'SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE username = ? and email = ?';
PREPARE stmt2 FROM @s;
SET @a = 'foo';
SET @b = 'bar';
EXECUTE stmt2 USING @a, @b;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3a80/1)

Comment: Is it possible to fill placeholders and execute SELECT query in single command?

Comment: what do you mean by fill placeholders? you can create a stored procedure from that.

Comment: Im wondering if its possible to use placeholders, provide values for placeholders and execute query in same sql command.

Comment: if that's the case, why do you still want to use place holders when you have already a value in line on the query?

Comment: oh yea, now I understand what ? marks do. And I figured out how to use them in the ORM Im using. Like so: User.where("username = ? OR email = ?", username, email)[0]